# how to display a svg QR via html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, svg, png, html2canvas

i have a QR code generated via `fetch(https://api.qr-code-generator.com/v1...)`

when i get the image as JPG or PNG, i try do render it before download as a canva via

```
html2canvas(document.body, {width:1680, height:800,   scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0}).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

the canva is good but the QR is missing

i also tryed with the QR as a SVG and on the canva the size of the QR is like 5 times bigger than on the html

i believe i'm not using html2canvas as i should, could someone tell me where i'm wrong?

Comment: This work for me: `{ allowTaint: false, useCORS: true }`

Answer (score 0):

found it, it was because my img is on a created url so i needed to add `allowTaint:true` to my html2canvas func

Answer (score 0):

Even i am getting the same problem html2canvas seems not to convert any external source image even if u use useCors or allowTaint u will have to convert the image into the the image data i.e convert image to base64 then use it in your html part and see if it works.